# Facing error when trying to link firebase analytics to microsoft clarity

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4, ms-clarity

Hi I am trying to link google analytics with Microsoft clarity but I use firebase to add google analytics

[image]

when I pressed the get started button I authenticated and gave it all the permissions it needed
[image]

But it shows

[image]

I have my site on google anaylitics can anyone please help me

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Clarity Actually Push Data to Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459668/does-clarity-actually-push-data-to-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first screenshot says:

> Google Analytics 4 support coming soon.

Firebase works with Google Analytics 4. So the integration is not yet available.