# Does Clarity Actually Push Data to Google Analytics?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, google-analytics, sharepoint-online, ms-clarity

## Does Clarity Actually Push Data to Google Analytics?

###### Context A:

I started a project for our company for internal intranet analytics so they can learn more about which pages work, which ones don't, popular documents, etc. I found Clarity (*and thought this is great*) it says that it pushes information to Google Analytics, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

*Additional context at the bottom to ensure question clarity, pun intended.*

###### Confusing / Misleading Documentation:

Microsoft can you answer this question or reply to my other emails that you and I were working back and forth on? Your [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/ga-integration#how-does-clarity-integration-work) says one thing (*the quote below*), but that doesn't seem to be accurate.

> ***How does Clarity integration work?***
>
> > Clarity will create a custom dimension called the 'Clarity Playback URL'. **Data will start flowing into Google Analytics from the Clarity JavaScript you've added to your site without any more changes**.

###### My Question:

So is this accurate or not, does Clarity pass information over or is this incorrectly describing Clarity behavior and that the two need to independently gather data for it to work correctly?

###### Initial Microsoft Response:

> Sometimes it takes about 1 - 2 days to populate the initial data, if you still don’t see the data by then, you can reach out again!

###### Second Microsoft Response:

> The account/web property that is connected has no rows in it for any query. Could you please double check and connect an account which contains data.

###### Final Thoughts:

So which one is it? There is no documentation on *this* and the project I am working on is at a standstill because of *this*, please advise so I can either continue forward with *this* or move on to a different solution because ms-clarity doesn't seem to be working as documented.

###### Context B:

I originally started in on this project because the previous Google Analytics that were linked into the intranet stopped working after modern / online updates (*not sure which one did it, that all happened before I got here*) and I had to get special approval to use Clarity and we only went with Clarity because of this piece in the documentation that essentially told us we could re-make the link between the intranet and Google Analytics as well as get more functionality coupled with Clarity.

We also did not want to do a weird patch job to get Google Analytics injected into pages and I told them a SPPKG of Clarity would do the trick... however, here we are now.

Answer (score 1):

Clarity DOES NOT *push* data to Google Analytics. You have to gather data using Clarity and Google Analytics SEPERATLEY, and then when you integrate Clarity will work with Google Analytics to bring the data together.

So you CANNOT only install Clarity, and then expect to integrate with Google Analytics to push Clarity gathered data to Google Analytics.